# Why does attoparsec need manyTill if it backtracks?

Tags: parsing, haskell, backtracking, parser-combinators, attoparsec

Consider the usage of these different parser combinators.

```
import Control.Applicative.Combinators
import Text.Regex.Applicative
 
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let parser1 = sym '"' *> manyTill anySym (sym '"')
  print $ match parser1 "\"abc\""
  let parser2 = sym '"' *> many anySym <* sym '"'
  print $ match parser2 "\"abc\""
```

```
import Control.Applicative.Combinators            
import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP hiding(many, manyTill)
 
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let parser1 = char '"' *> manyTill get (char '"')
  print $ readP_to_S parser1 "\"abc\""
  let parser2 = char '"' *> many get <* char '"'
  print $ readP_to_S parser2 "\"abc\""
```

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
 
import Control.Applicative.Combinators
import Data.Attoparsec.Text hiding(manyTill)
 
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let parser1 = char '"' *> manyTill anyChar (char '"')
  print $ parseOnly parser1 "\"abc\""
  let parser2 = char '"' *> many anyChar <* char '"'
  print $ parseOnly parser2 "\"abc\""
```

```
import Control.Applicative.Combinators
import Text.Megaparsec hiding(many, manyTill)
import Data.Void

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let parser1 = single '"' *> manyTill anySingle (single '"') :: Parsec Void String String
  print $ parseMaybe parser1 "\"abc\""
  let parser2 = single '"' *> many anySingle <* single '"' :: Parsec Void String String
  print $ parseMaybe parser2 "\"abc\""
```

With all four of them, the `manyTill` parser successfully matches `abc`, since this doesn't depend on backtracking. With `regex-applicative` and `ReadP`, the `many` parser also successfully matches `abc`, since they both backtrack by default. With `megaparsec`, the `many` parser fails to match, since it doesn't backtrack by default. So far, everything makes sense. However, with `attoparsec`, the `many` parser fails to match, even though it does backtrack: [its documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.13.2.4/docs/Data-Attoparsec-Text.html) says "attoparsec parsers always backtrack on failure" and "if you feed incremental input to an a parser, it will require memory proportional to the amount of input you supply. (This is necessary to support arbitrary backtracking.)". Why is this? Isn't that supposed to be exactly what backtracking is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The meaning of "backtracking" in the Attoparsec documentation is different than the meaning of backtracking for the other backtracking parsers.

It helps to review what "backtracking" means when using `try` for a Parsec or Megaparsec parser.  These parsers have a concept of failing after consuming input ("consume err" = cerr) versus failing after consuming nothing ("empty err" = eerr).  For these parsers, the `p <|> q` alternative operator treats failure of `p` differently if it's cerr (fail the whole `p <|> q` immediately) versus eerr (try the alternative `q` instead).  The `try` function backtracks by converting cerr to eerr.  That is, `try p <|> q` will "backtrack" an erroneous consumption of the input stream in the event `p` fails with cerr.  It's a **single step of backtracking on failure within alternatives** (though with nested `try` calls, multiple steps of backtracking can be performed in a sequence/cascade of parse failures).

Attoparsec doesn't differentiate betweeen cerr and eerr, so it's as if all parsers are surrounded by `try` calls.  This means that it automatically performs **multiple steps of backtracking on failure within alternatives**.

`ReadP` backtracks implicitly by simultaneously evaluating every possible parse in parallel, discarding those that ever fail, and picking the "first" one that remains.  **It "backtracks" failures over a tree of all possible parses, whether the failures were generated in the context of an alternative or not.**

It turns out that "multiple steps of backtracking on failure within alternatives" is a more modest form of backtracking than "backtracking over a tree of all possible parses".

A couple of simplified examples may help show the difference.  Consider the parser:

```
(anyChar *> char 'a') <|> char 'b'
```

and the input string `"bd"`.   This parser fails with Parsec/Megaparsec.  The left-hand alternative consumes the `"b"` with `anyChar` before failing, having consumed input (cerr), and the whole parser fails.  This works fine with Attoparsec, though:  the left-hand alternative fails at `char 'a'`, and Attoparsec backtracks on this failure within an alternative to try `char 'b'` which succeeds.  It also works with `ReadP` which constructs all possible parses in parallel, before discarding the parse from the left-hand alternative when `char 'a'` fails, resulting in a single successful parse by `char 'b'`.

Now, consider the parser:

```
(anyChar <|> pure '*') *> char 'b'
```

and the input string `"b"`.  (Recall that `pure '*'` consumes nothing and always succeeds.)  This parser fails with Parsec/Megaparsec, because `anyChar` parses the `"b"`, the `pure '*'` is ignored, and the empty string isn't matched by `char 'b'`.  It also fails with Attoparsec:  `anyChar` successfully parses the `"b"`, and there's no failure in the context of an alternative, so no backtracking to try the `pure '*'` alternative.  The attempt to parse the empty string with `char 'b'` subsequently fails.  (*This* failure, if it occurs in the context of another alternative might result in backtracking of *that* alternative, but never reconsideration of this `pure '*'` alternative.)

In contrast, this parses fine with `ReadP`.  `ReadP` parses the alternatives in parallel, considering both `anyChar` parsing the `"b"` and `pure '*'` parsing nothing.  When the `char 'b'` parse is tried, it fails on the former but succeeds on the latter.

Back to your example.  When parsing with Attoparsec, because:

```
many p = ((:) <$> p <*> many p) <|> pure []
```

the left alternative `(:) <$> anyChar <*> many anyChar` will continue to successfully match all the way up to and including the point where `anyChar` matches the closing quotation mark.  At EOF, the left-hand side will fail (without consuming input, though Attoparsec doesn't care about that), and the right-hand side will succeed.  The only failure within an alternative is at EOF, which didn't consume anything anyway, so Attoparsec's automatic "backtracking" plays no role; Megaparsec would have done the same thing.  Anyway, once this `many anyChar` has succeeded, it won't be revisited, even if the terminating `char '"'` subsequently fails.

So, *that*'s why you need `manyTill` to explicitly watch for the terminating character.

Comment: Okay, I think this makes sense. Is this a valid summary? "`attoparsec` only backtracks when the left side of `<|>` consumes some characters and then fails. If the left side of `<|>` succeeds, unlike `ReadP` and `regex-applicative`, `attoparsec` will never try the right side, even if the parse fails later."

Comment: How do you explain `Megaparsec`'s behavior on the OP's example?

Comment: @dfeuer -- it fails, too, right?  In the OP's example, the only failure in an alternative is a failure that consumes no input (when `anyChar` fails on EOF), so Megaparsec and Attoparsec behave the same.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica, yes I think that summary is correct.